# No financial advice disclaimer in a research paper

Tags: publications, paper-submission, legal-issues

I'm about to submit my research paper to a journal concerning finance and investments. In the work, I say something like:

> The results show that fields/industries/companies "A", "B" and "C"
> appeared to be a reasonable choice for investment during the
> investigated period.

I wonder if I should add a kind of a disclaimer that the paper's information is not a financial recommendation? Am I supposed do it in a scientific paper? If yes, how can it be properly done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Academic papers in finance do not usually need a disclaimer like this, since the context of academic work means that it is understood that the work is a general scientific work, rather than a specific piece of advice to a financial client.  Nevertheless, if you're worried then it can't hurt to give a disclaimer, and I doubt the journal will object (unless they want to prevent the floodgates opening on the issue).  Something like the following should get the job done:

> Disclaimer: The present publication is an academic paper published for general scientific purposes and is not intended to constitute financial advice to any person.   The author hereby warns all readers not to rely on the information in this paper for financial investment decisions or any other financial purposes, and to seek independent financial advice from an appropriate professional.  The author does not give any warranty as to the accuracy of any information in the paper to any person for purposes of financial decisions.

My own disclaimer: The present post is for general knowledge in academic discussion only and is not intended as legal advice to any person.  All readers are hereby warned not to rely on this post for purposes of obtaining legal protections or for any other legal matter.  If you want to obtain a legally effective disclaimer then you should obtain advice from an appropriate lawyer in your jurisdiction.  I give no warranty as to the effectiveness of the above disclaimer.

Answer (score 1):

Your formulation makes it clear that you are talking about the past, not the future. By changing the words to "appear to have been a reasonable choice" this could become even clearer.

Scientific papers do not usually carry this type of disclaimer. They are not meant to be read among the public, but by scientific peers who would not be able to read this as a recommendation for the future.

Comment: Would you answer change if I talked about the future?

Comment: Then you would be providing financial advise. Unless you acted maliciously, I do not see how you could be held liable, but then it is a matter for the lawyers.